# Stretch image over multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I stretch the background-image of container 1 to container 2?

```
<div class="main_container">
   <div class="container" id="container-1"></div>
   <div class="container" id="container-2"></div>
</div>
```

I used this function, but it does not work always.

```
var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;
var i = 0;
$(".container").each(function (ind, el) {
    $(this).css("background-position", posX.toString() + "% " + posY.toString() + "%");
    posX += 20;
    i++;
    if (i == 1) {
        i = 0;
        posX = 0;
        posY += 0;
    }
})
```

---

Here is an image of the 2 containers:

[image: image of 2 containers]

---

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the parent `.main_container` contains only the 2 `.container` divs and the background image has to be loaded into the page via `#container-1` then I would use JavaScript to transfer the background image from `#container-1` to `.main_container`. The background image would then cover the entire area - both `#container-1` and `#container-2`.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.main_container')
const image = document.querySelector('#container-1').style.backgroundImage
parent.style.backgroundImage = image
```

Comment: Good solution, but I have margins between one and the other container. This covers the entire area, but I need the images only on the cotainer, so that the margins remain empty. Also, there are 7 containers in total.

Comment: Then I would still set the parent element to have the background image and just add borders to the child containers to simulate margins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```css
.main_container {
  align-content: stretch;
  background-image: <url>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have margins between one and the other container. This covers the entire area, but I need the images only on the cotainer, so that the margins remain empty.